# C++ STL or Template and DLL

Tags: c++

Can I have C++ Shared library in which there is exported function which return `std::vector<t>`

Comment: Maybe you wanted to ask something else?

Comment: @ereOn as Alessa  mentioned, Avinash might have had something else in his mind. I am not sure this is proper way to comment. BTW, do you know any of those countries which forbid returning vectors from functions ?

Comment: @Jagannath: I was indeed joking because I thought the question was poorly written. A law forbiding that wouldn't make any sense. (Anyway, it seems the comment was moderated - fair enough to me)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, provided the DLL and the C++ code that consumes it

- are built using the same C++ compiler
- are using the same version of the STL (this may be sensitive to STL debug defines too)
- are using the same shared runtime library (i.e. shared, debug vs release, single vs multiple threaded, same version) so that both allocate and free objects on the same memory heap

then it should work fine. There might be a little leeway with some of these but in general it's better to be safe and keep everything identical if possible.

Answer (score 1):

If in `std::vector<t>` the `t` is an unknown type, i.e. if you want to store a `template` in a shared library, as opposed to some fixed template instantiation, *the answer is **no***.

There would be needed a way to inject type `t` into the shared library, but there isn't.

In code terms:

```
// This is NOT possible:
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> something () {...}

// This IS:
std::vector<int> something () {...}
```